# ¿Como implementar Lazy-Loading con rutas hijas en Angular?

Tags: angular, rutas, lazy-loading

Cordial saludo

La presente es para manifestar una duda técnica, como se podría implementar rutas hijas para un componente padre utilizando la técnica de lazy loading, no he logrado lograr que se me visualice un componente hijo dentro de un modulo generado mediante ****lazy loading****, tengo lo siguiente pero no funciona.

Este es el modulo AboutComponent

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {AboutComponent} from './about.component';
import {ChildrenComponent} from './children/children.component';

  const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '', component: AboutComponent,
   children: [
   {
    path: 'children', component: ChildrenComponent
     }
   ]
 },
]; 
 @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AboutRoutingModule {
}
```

Este es el modulo principal de las rutas

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {
    path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./about/about.module')
      .then(m => m.AboutModule)
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente estructura te permitirá mostrar el componente en la ruta `/about/children`

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
      path: '',
      component: AboutComponent,
    },

    {
      path: 'children',
      component: ChildrenComponent
    }

  },
```

En esta configuración visualizaras `AboutComponent` en el path `/about`

Comment: Mi compañero, lo que necesito es tratar de mantener en el mismo componente about pero cuando ingrese a la ruta children se observe dentro de ese mismo el componente children.

Comment: Haa, ok. Pregunta, pusiste el `<router-outlet>`  en  `about.component.html`?

Comment: SI pero no me funciona, no me muestra nada

Comment: Por la estructura que tienes, generas dos modulos, `about.module` y y `about-routing.module`. Estas importando `about-routing` dentro de `about.module`? No lo publicaste tampoco.